# Error installing brave browser

Tags: curl, openpgp, brave

I tried to install brave in linux using the command below, but the following error is showing:

```
curl -s https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc | sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/brave-browser-release.gpg add -

gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using a debian